# Add to calendar strange behaviour when used with angular expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/2ELLB/270/

I am trying to use add to calendar with angularjs. I have a strange issue the value is binding from the controller to the html page, But when I check the link instead of the bind value the link is coming as

```
$scope.date = 2014-05-04 12:00:00;
```

> %7B%7Bdate%7D%7D

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect

```
$scope.date = 2014-05-04 12:00:00;
```

It may be like this

```
$scope.date = "2014-05-04 12:00:00";
```

In your code you have not included the ng-app and ng-controller

```
<span class="addtocalendar atc-style-blue">
```

should have been like this

```
<span ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="new" class="addtocalendar atc-style-blue">
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/2ELLB/271/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time but ..nope it does not work,.. when i click on the button in the result and click icalendar i get the following error message `AddToCalendar.com gets invalid event parameters`

Comment: well that's another issue altogether check the icalendar url how you need to pass the parameter  .In the question you had mentioned that %7B%7Bdate%7D%7D is getting passed that is fixed.